# Let $f,g:(a,b) \to R$ be two differentiable functions where $f'(x)=g'(x)$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

Prove that the function $h(x)=f(x)-g(x)$ is a constant function.

I know that $f'(a)$ is defined as $\lim_{x\to a} \frac{f(x)-f(a)}{x-a}$ and I was thinking I could do something with setting $g'(x)=f'(x)$ and the above and working something out but I'm sort of getting stuck. I don't think I'm allowed to use the fact that the antiderivative of 0 is a constant function. Thanks

Comment: do you know the mean value theorem of differential calculus ?

Comment: @KonstantinosKanak0glou Edit: Oops, misread lol, i do know the mvt of differential calculus

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First let us prove the following theorem:

Let a function $f$ defined on an interval $\Delta$. If:

- $f$ is continuous on $\Delta$, and
- $f'(x)=0$ for any inner point of $\Delta$
  then $f$ is constant on $\Delta$.

**Proof:** It suffices to show that for any $x_1,x_2\in\Delta \ $, $ \ f(x_1)=f(x_2)$.

Considering $x_1<x_2$, then in the interval $[x_1,x_2]$ $f$ satisfies the assumptions of the mean value theorem. Thus, there is $\xi\in(x_1,x_2)$, such that 
$$f'(\xi)=\frac{f(x_2)-f(x_1)}{x_2-x_1}$$
But $\xi$ is an inner point of $\Delta$ so $f'(\xi)=0$ which leads us to 
$$f(x_1)=f(x_2)$$
The same applies in case $x_1>x_2$ (now applying the mean value theorem in $[x_2,x_1]$). Thus, in any case 
$$f(x)=\textrm{const}$$
in $\Delta$.

Now, the answer to your question is immediate if you apply the above theorem on the function $f-g$.